# Feed value from a C# .Net Framework Console Application into a Console Command

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console

I want to feed the value I get from a .NET Framework console application into the change directory command with the extra argument `/d`. I don't know how I can achieve this and especially not how I can make my console application return a value that can be used in the command line interface.

What I want to do is something like this in cmd.exe:

```
myapplication.exe argument1 | cd /d
```

But how can I do this?

My application would use the `argument1` in order to print/return a path which should be then used by the `cmd.exe` change directory command in order to get to that path. Does anyone know how to do this? (I know how to write C# console applications and how to use the argument my only problem is with outputting the result and feeding it into the cd command)

Comment: I am really not sure what you're asking. This is my understanding of your requirements... Write a C# console application that receives an argument as input and then either starts cmd.exe to execute cd (with arguments) or executes cd in its own console window (if that's even possible? idk). If this is accurate, then I don't understand what the purpose of executing cd has for you.

Comment: I want to execute my program in the command line which outputs a path which should then be fed into the cd command to change the opened cmd.exe to that path.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, but you could do it using a combination of a batch file and piping the output of your application to a file. Create a .bat file containing the following and run it:

```
myapplication.exe argument1 > output.txt
set /P cdtarget=<output.txt
cd %cdtarget%
```

Comment: It is a way that works, but as you said a bit hacky and impractical, so I hope there is a cleaner way, but thank you.

Comment: I still am searching for a way for getting this effect only with one .exe c# file but I found a cleaner solution for doing it with a batch file. If you use "myapplication.exe argument1 | set /p directory=" the output from my application file will be directly set as the directory variable and can then be used with the change directory command.

Comment: I had a niggling feeling there was a more elegant way of doing it - my batch scripting is a little rusty tbh :-)